# Last item of the sequence?

Tags: sequence

3968, 63, 8, 3.

I'm lost here, thought it had something to do with square roots but my guess was 1. Usually I see questions like this and it's 4...16...25, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you provide proper attribution so we know where this puzzle came from?

Comment: It appears to be from [matrix67.com](https://www.matrix67.com/iqtest/).

Comment: The test seems to be the copyright of Nathan Haselbauer and Mike Dickheiser, and in the introduction to the test they write "We ask that you do not share your answers in any public forum in order to maintain the integrity of the test."

Comment: Changing the question does not absolve you of the need to provide attribution for content you're posting here that is not your own.  Yes, you need the permission of the original content creator to post their work here. But even if you have it (and merely being unaware that you *don't* have it is by no means the same thing!), you still need to disclose the original source.

Comment: **I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided.** —
It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, **[proper attribution](/help/referencing)** is required. Please [edit] to include (at minimum) where this came from—any additional context you
 can provide is also helpful to solvers—then vote to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I  believe the answer is

> 2

Because:

> $\sqrt{3968 + 1} = 63$
> $\sqrt{63 + 1} = 8$
> $\sqrt{8 + 1} = 3$
> $\sqrt{3 + 1} = 2$

P.s: I guess this is a new question not related to `matrix67.com`

Comment: Yeah, I changed the question once I was informed the authors didn't want the answers publicly posted.